# Python Regex - Extract number from String with positive lookahead

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I am currently starting with regex and try to understand some commands. One problem I stumbled upon is that I can use a positive lookahead like

```
asdaf = re.compile(r'[1-9](?=u)')
asdaf.findall("rm4m3455ukdfr6i")
```

which results in:

```
['5']
```

So far so good. However, if extend the numbers to more then one

```
bsdaf = re.compile(r'[1-9]*(?=u)')
bsdaf.findall("rm4m3455ukdfr6i")
```

I get this list

```
['3455', '']
```

Can someone explain why there is a second empty entry in the list and how to avoid this second entry?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `*` means *0 or more*, i.e. `[1-9]*` can match an empty string. Use `+`. Never use empty string matching patterns if you do not expect empty matches in the output.

Comment: The first match is `3455`. The regex's internal string pointer is then located between `'5'` and `'u'`. The next match is then attempted. The lookahead `(?=u)` is again satisfied, as is `[1-9]*` with a zero-width (empty string) match.